# What icons are available to use when displaying a notification with libnotify?

Tags: python, pygtk, libnotify

I'm using the [libnotify](http://roscidus.com/desktop/node/336) library to display a notification in Ubuntu. I would ideally like to display a battery of some sort (since my app is a battery meter).

The types of icons I can use are:

1. a URI specifying the icon file name (e.g. file://path/to/my-icon.png)
2. a 'stock' icon name. One that would succeed in a call to gtk_icontheme_lookup() (e.g. 'stock-delete') Note: these are not necessarily normal GTK stock icons - any theme icon will work.
3. a pixbuf

I would ideally like to use option #2, however I can't find out the names of the available icons. How can I find which icons are available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily find out using [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/) itself:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> print "\n".join(name for name in dir(gtk) if name.startswith("STOCK_"))
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
STOCK_ABOUT
STOCK_ADD
STOCK_APPLY
STOCK_BOLD
STOCK_CANCEL
STOCK_CAPS_LOCK_WARNING
STOCK_CDROM
STOCK_CLEAR
STOCK_CLOSE
STOCK_COLOR_PICKER
STOCK_CONNECT
STOCK_CONVERT
STOCK_COPY
STOCK_CUT
STOCK_DELETE
STOCK_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION
STOCK_DIALOG_ERROR
STOCK_DIALOG_INFO
STOCK_DIALOG_QUESTION
STOCK_DIALOG_WARNING
STOCK_DIRECTORY
STOCK_DISCARD
STOCK_DISCONNECT
STOCK_DND
STOCK_DND_MULTIPLE
STOCK_EDIT
STOCK_EXECUTE
STOCK_FILE
STOCK_FIND
STOCK_FIND_AND_REPLACE
STOCK_FLOPPY
STOCK_FULLSCREEN
STOCK_GOTO_BOTTOM
STOCK_GOTO_FIRST
STOCK_GOTO_LAST
STOCK_GOTO_TOP
STOCK_GO_BACK
STOCK_GO_DOWN
STOCK_GO_FORWARD
STOCK_GO_UP
STOCK_HARDDISK
STOCK_HELP
STOCK_HOME
STOCK_INDENT
STOCK_INDEX
STOCK_INFO
STOCK_ITALIC
STOCK_JUMP_TO
STOCK_JUSTIFY_CENTER
STOCK_JUSTIFY_FILL
STOCK_JUSTIFY_LEFT
STOCK_JUSTIFY_RIGHT
STOCK_LEAVE_FULLSCREEN
STOCK_MEDIA_FORWARD
STOCK_MEDIA_NEXT
STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE
STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY
STOCK_MEDIA_PREVIOUS
STOCK_MEDIA_RECORD
STOCK_MEDIA_REWIND
STOCK_MEDIA_STOP
STOCK_MISSING_IMAGE
STOCK_NETWORK
STOCK_NEW
STOCK_NO
STOCK_OK
STOCK_OPEN
STOCK_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
STOCK_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
STOCK_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
STOCK_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
STOCK_PAGE_SETUP
STOCK_PASTE
STOCK_PREFERENCES
STOCK_PRINT
STOCK_PRINT_ERROR
STOCK_PRINT_PAUSED
STOCK_PRINT_PREVIEW
STOCK_PRINT_REPORT
STOCK_PRINT_WARNING
STOCK_PROPERTIES
STOCK_QUIT
STOCK_REDO
STOCK_REFRESH
STOCK_REMOVE
STOCK_REVERT_TO_SAVED
STOCK_SAVE
STOCK_SAVE_AS
STOCK_SELECT_ALL
STOCK_SELECT_COLOR
STOCK_SELECT_FONT
STOCK_SORT_ASCENDING
STOCK_SORT_DESCENDING
STOCK_SPELL_CHECK
STOCK_STOP
STOCK_STRIKETHROUGH
STOCK_UNDELETE
STOCK_UNDERLINE
STOCK_UNDO
STOCK_UNINDENT
STOCK_YES
STOCK_ZOOM_100
STOCK_ZOOM_FIT
STOCK_ZOOM_IN
STOCK_ZOOM_OUT
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look it up in the [Free Desktop Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html). It looks like the icons you need are "battery", "battery-caution", and "battery-low".

Comment: It's weird that they aren't displaying the actual images.

Answer (score 0):

The icons are specify in "freedesktop icon-theme-spec", you can read here:

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout

- So, the icons "availables" are in any of this folders:

HOME/.icons

/usr/share/icons

/usr/share/pixmaps